# Как лаконично и красиво поместить число в диапазон?

Tags: python

Следующий фрагмент кода бросается в глаза своей "топорностью", поэтому хочу его сделать более красивым.

Делаю простой конвертер изображения из rgb в hex, поэтому значение должно быть на интервале [0;255]

```
if number < 0:
    number = 0
if number > 255:
    number = 255
```

Можно ли средствами Python уменьшить код?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def clip(val, min_=0, max_=255):
    return max(min_, min(max_, val))
```

тесты:

```
In [12]: clip(100)
Out[12]: 100

In [13]: clip(1000)
Out[13]: 255

In [14]: clip(-1000)
Out[14]: 0
```

---

[по совету @Bogdan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021747/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd/1021750?noredirect=1#comment1737954_1021750), добавлю [вариант с использованием тернарного оператора](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989866/5741205):

```
def clip(val, min_=0, max_=255):
    return min_ if val < min_ else max_ if val > max_ else val
```

---

для тех, кто использует Numpy - в Numpy существует готовая функция [np.clip()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

Пример:

```
import numpy as np

In [34]: a = np.arange(10)

In [35]: a
Out[35]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [36]: clipped = np.clip(a, 3, 8)

In [37]: clipped
Out[37]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8])
```

Comment: Похожий [вариант на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989866/5441023), но без вызовов дополнительных функций

Comment: @Bogdan, была у меня мысль сначала - использовать тернарный оператор, но код будет чуть длиннее, хотя наверное более читаемый. Добавлю как вариант решения... ;)